# Antlr Lexer Quoted String Predicate

Tags: string, cpu-word, antlr, lexer, quotes

I'm trying to build a lexer to tokenize lone words and quoted strings. I got the following:

```
STRING:    QUOTE (options {greedy=false;} : . )* QUOTE ;
WS    :    SPACE+ { $channel = HIDDEN; } ;
WORD  :    ~(QUOTE|SPACE)+ ;
```

For the corner cases, it needs to parse:

```
"string" word1" word2
```

As three tokens: `"string"` as STRING and `word1"` and `word2` as WORD. Basically, if there is a last quote, it needs to be part of the WORD were it is. If the quote is surrounded by white spaces, it should be a WORD.

I tried this rule for WORD, without success:

```
WORD:    ~(QUOTE|SPACE)+
    |    (~(QUOTE|SPACE)* QUOTE ~QUOTE*)=> ~(QUOTE|SPACE)* QUOTE ~(QUOTE|SPACE)* ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found something that could do the trick without resorting to writing Java code:

```
    fragment QUOTE
            :   '"' ;
    fragment SPACE
            :   (' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\u000C'|'\n') ;

    WS      :   SPACE+ {$channel=HIDDEN;};
    PHRASE  :   QUOTE (options {greedy=false;} : . )* QUOTE ;
    WORD    :   (~(QUOTE|SPACE)* QUOTE ~QUOTE* EOF)=> ~(QUOTE|SPACE)* QUOTE ~(SPACE)*
            |   ~(QUOTE|SPACE)+ ;
```

That way, the predicate differentiate/solves for both:

```
    PHRASE  :   QUOTE (options {greedy=false;} : . )* QUOTE ;
```

and

```
            |   ~(QUOTE|SPACE)+ ;
```